# Python panda data frames datatime only shows date or time. How to show both?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

How can I show both the **date** and **time** in my `'Time'` column inside the csv file? I have shown some different examples of what I am seeing?

where df 'Time' looks like

"2021-11-01 08:00:00"

**Example 1. Shows correct in console but not in csv file.**

```
    posix_time = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='ms')
    df['Time']  = posix_time
    df.to_csv (r'dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)

0     2021-11-01 08:00:00

 # In csv file ??? why not date and time like above only date ????
      2021-11-01
```

**Example 2. Shows correct in console and correct in file only date.**

```
    posix_time = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='ms').dt.date
    df['Time']  = posix_time
    df.to_csv (r'dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)

0      2021-11-01

# In csv file 
       2021-11-01
```

**Example 3. Shows correct in console and in file only time.**

```
    posix_time = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='ms').dt.time
    df['Time']  = posix_time
    df.to_csv (r'dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)

0      08:00:00

# In csv file 
       08:00:00
```

Comment: You can format the datetime object as desired with [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

Comment: Use code from example 1 above and make a string column with desired format; `df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `str` value to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime()`. For more information of how to set `format` parameter in `pd.to_datetime()`, see https://www.dataindependent.com/pandas/pandas-to-datetime/

```
#file.csv
Time
2021-11-01 08:00:00
2021-11-02 09:00:00
2021-11-03 10:00:00
2021-11-04 11:00:00
2021-11-05 12:00:00
```

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = './file.csv'  # to read your csv file
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
print(df)

# For example, df will be printed look like:
#   Time
#0  2021-11-01 08:00:00
#1  2021-11-02 09:00:00
#2  2021-11-03 10:00:00
#3  2021-11-04 11:00:00
#4  2021-11-05 12:00:00

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # to convert str to datetime format

df.to_csv('result.csv')  # You can see that Time data is saved as "date + time", not just date or time.
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is struggling to convert string to datetime, but the other way around: how the get date/time as string with a certain format.